# What is the correct equation for conditional relative entropy and why

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, entropy

I was trying to understand the concept of conditional relative entropy.

As in:

$$D(P(X\mid Y) ||Q(X\mid Y))= E [\log\frac{P(X\mid Y)}{Q(X\mid Y)}]$$

I would have thought that its equations would be:

$$D(P(X\mid Y) ||Q(X\mid Y)) = \sum_{x,y} p(x\mid y) \log \frac{p(x\mid y)}{q(x\mid y)}$$

> However, the text book that I was reading said the following:
>
> We can think of conditional relative entropy $D(P(X\mid Y) ||Q(X\mid Y))= E
>  [\log\frac{P(X\mid Y)}{Q(X\mid Y)}]$ as a weighted sum of the relative
>   entropies between the conditional distributions given different values
>   of y
>
> $$D(P(X\mid Y) ||Q(X\mid Y)) = \sum_y p(y) D(P(X\mid y) ||Q(X\mid y)) $$

but with a little algebra, the previous interpretation leads me to the following equation:

$$D(P(X|Y) ||Q(X|Y)) = \sum_{x,y} p(x,y) \log \frac{p(x|y)}{q(x|y)}$$

however, it is not the equation that I expected:

$$D(P(X\mid Y) ||Q(X\mid Y)) = \sum_{x,y} p(x\mid y) \log \frac{p(x\mid y)}{q(x\mid y)}$$

Does somebody understand the difference between them and which one is the correct version and why?

Answer (score 4):

For discrete distributions, a "relative entropy" (ordinary or conditional) is by definition an *expected value* of the logarithm of a ratio of probability mass functions, whereas the expression you consider, viz.

$$\sum_{x,y} p(x\mid y) \log \frac{p(x\mid y)}{q(x\mid y)}
$$

is *not* of the required form, because

$$\sum_{x,y} p(x\mid y) \ne 1.
$$

On the other hand,

$$\sum_{x} p(x\mid y) = 1,
$$

so the expression

$$\sum_{x} p(x\mid y) \log \frac{p(x\mid y)}{q(x\mid y)}
$$

*is* of the required form, and the quantity so defined is called the "relative entropy" of the conditional distributions **given $Y = y$**, denoted by $D(P(X\mid y) ||Q(X\mid y))$; furthermore, because this is a function of $y$ only, it has the expected value

$$\sum_y p(y) D(P(X\mid y) ||Q(X\mid y)) = \sum_y p(y) \sum_{x} p(x\mid y) \log \frac{p(x\mid y)}{q(x\mid y)} = \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x\mid y)}{q(x\mid y)}
$$

which, by an abuse of terminology and notation, is called the "conditional relative entropy" denoted by $D(P(X\mid Y) ||Q(X\mid Y)$.